# Unknown Coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, wgs84

I'm new at GIS. I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 and trying to geocode some addresses. I used a geocoding service which gave the coordinates in this format:

```
POINT(102778.307715144 105888.168842117)
```

I don't know how to handle that, so I tried the Convert Coordinate Notation tool, but it throws me an error: output file already exists and it cannot be overwritten (the issue must be other since the file doesn't really exists).
By the way, I tried to convert that to `GCS_WGS_1984`, which is the coordinate system I always use.

Any clue?

The address is located in Buenos Aires, Argentina. Regarding the geocoding service, I can't give more details because it's an application downloaded from a goverment's site, and I didn't find any documentation there.

I also used other common projections used in Argentina to show the x y values, but it didn't work.

SOLVED:

What happened is that the City of Buenos Aires has a custom projected system. I downloaded some public shapefiles and there I got the exact information, so I used that data to draw the x y coordinates, then transformed it into a feature class, and then used the project tool to convert it to WGS_1984.

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Comment: it is not possible to answer this question if you do not provide information about the possible location of this address (either giving the address, the WGS 84 coordinate where it should be or the geocoding service that you are using)

Answer (score 2):

I googled Buenos Aires and "sistema de coordenadas" and found a [PDF](https://recursos-data.buenosaires.gob.ar/ckan2/proyecciones-gkba.pdf) that has this information.

```
GeoCRS (datum): Campo Inchauspe 
Projection: Transverse Mercator
Central Meridian: -58.4627 
Latitude of Origin: -34.6297166 
Scale Factor: 0.999998 
False Easting: 100000.0 m 
False Northing: 100000.0 m
Unit: Meter
```

The document doesn't have a date, so it's possible that the same projection and parameters are being used, but with a newer geographic coordinate reference system.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkennedy, you are right, I found the same yesterday, it's a custom projection, I edited my question. Thanks a lot for taking the time